# Can't access Repository functions

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, repository

I am creating a simple doctrine project, and I had an example that works using a VM, but I am doing in Windows and I can access any Repository function in my Repository class.

User Entity:

```
<?php

namespace Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="user_user_group_id", columns={"user_group_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
```

User Repository:

```
<?php

namespace Repository;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException;
use Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

/**
 * Class UserRepository
 *
 * @package Entity
 */
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
     /**
     * Return all users
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function findAll()
    {
        return $this->em->getRepository("Entity\User")->findAll();
    }

    /**
     * Find an user by id
     *
     * @param $id
     *
     * @return null|object
     */
    public function findOne($id)
    {
        return $this->em->getRepository("Entity\User")->find($id);
    }
```

When I try to access `findOne` function in my Controller, I receive this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Repository\UserRepository::find()

And when I try to access `findAll` function in my Controller, I receive this error:

> Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached,
>   aborting!
>   `vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php` on line 187

To create the Entities I used:

```
orm:convert-mapping --force --from-database annotation ./src/Entity
orm:generate-entities ./src/Entity --generate-annotations=true
```

Thank you!

#### Update

https://gist.github.com/FelipeUmpierre/04d943bb97f47dfc3eef

Comment: The good news is that your mapping appear to be correct.  The not so good news is that your repository does not extend the doctrine repository class.  And your findAll/findOne methods make no sense at all.  There are plenty of doctrine repositories examples out there.

Comment: I will update after I fix this. I am now extending EntityRepository but I got this error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object`

Comment: More than likely your controller is not getting the repository correctly.  Check for typos or post your controller find code.

Comment: Your class needs to extend  `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository`... The `find` method will be in there.